# Highcharts/highstock mouse wheel scroll keeps scrolling on y-axis in

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working on asp.net MVC 5, i am using dot net highcharts to display my data

I wanted to add mouse wheel scrolling on y-axis when i am in zoom so i found bellow piece of code

```
(function (H) {

    //internal functions
    function stopEvent(e) {
        if (e) {
            if (e.preventDefault) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            if (e.stopPropagation) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
            e.cancelBubble = true;
        }
    }

    //the wrap
    H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'render', function (proceed) {
        var chart = this,
          mapNavigation = chart.options.mapNavigation;

        proceed.call(chart);

        // Add the mousewheel event
        H.addEvent(chart.container, document.onmousewheel === undefined ? 'DOMMouseScroll' : 'mousewheel', function (event) {

            var delta, extr, step, newMin, newMax, axis = chart.yAxis[0];

            e = chart.pointer.normalize(event);
            // Firefox uses e.detail, WebKit and IE uses wheelDelta
            delta = e.detail || -(e.wheelDelta / 120);
            delta = delta < 0 ? 1 : -1;

            if (chart.isInsidePlot(e.chartX - chart.plotLeft, e.chartY - chart.plotTop)) {
                extr = axis.getExtremes();
                step = (extr.max - extr.min) / 5 * delta;
                axis.setExtremes(extr.min + step, extr.max + step, true, false);
            }

            stopEvent(event); // Issue #5011, returning false from non-jQuery event does not prevent default
            return false;
        });
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

But there is a problem

1. The wheel is scrolling infinite times
2. I want it to enable only when i am in zoom

JsFiddle link would be in the comment section

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Here is the [JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/3q79ey8h/1/)

Comment: You can use map module and set a few options per each axis. Let me know if examples: http://jsfiddle.net/L6dxoj1p/1/ / http://jsfiddle.net/d_paul/pebez5w3/2/ / http://jsfiddle.net/d_paul/xcqd8ccb/11/ are correct with your expecations.

Comment: @SebastianBochan i don't want to zoom on scrool i want to scroll on y-axis when i am in zoom

Comment: How about the first demo? morever in other both demos, you can disable scrollbars. Chart is zoomed when you trigger mousewheel.